# What is the blessing on dough?

Tags: halacha, blessing, sources-mekorot, food, bread

Shulchan Aruch discusses the blessing on baked dough (various places - Hamotzi), fried dough (O.C. 168:10), raw grain kernels (Ha'adama - O.C. 208:4), flour (shehakol - 208:5), and various cooked mixtures with flour in them (mezonos or hamotzi - various locations, many of them in O.C. 208).  As far as I know, raw dough is not directly discussed.  My assumption would be that it is shehakol, but is it discussed anywhere explicitly?

The Gemara in Berachos 37a contrasts raw grain with baked and then cooked dough, and skips the stage of being uncooked dough:

> תניא הכוסס את החטה מברך עליה בורא פרי האדמה טחנה אפאה ובשלה בזמן שהפרוסות קיימות בתחלה מברך עליה המוציא לחם מן הארץ ולבסוף מברך עליה ג׳ ברכות אם אין הפרוסות קיימות בתחלה מברך עליה בורא מיני מזונות ולבסוף מברך עליה ברכה אחת מעין ג׳

Comment: https://twitter.com/cRcKosher/status/27849058925

Comment: Funny....looked at bracha index of Halachos of [Brachos](http://www.feldheim.com/halachos-of-brochos.html)....he had fried dough and doughnut, but not plain dough (though if he has it somewhere in the middle in a bigger discussion, I wouldn't know)

Comment: +0. Why would you want to eat raw dough? (Unless it's raw cookie dough, which is sweet and delicious.)

Comment: @unforgettableid Chapter 6 of Maseches Berachos has lengthy discussions about many things that I wouldn't want to eat. Do you like to eat raw flour?  I don't know why your personal culinary tastes should dictate what there should be halachic discussion about.

Comment: @yEz:  Good reply.  OK; let me respond.  The question shows research effort, and is clear, but I'm not sure that it's especially useful in _my_ life.  _That_ is why I've voted it +0.  (If this was a mistake, please correct me.)  Though, even though it may not be an important question in my life, I agree that all posts (whether practical or theoretical) improve the site.

Comment: @Yez: An [article](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) in our Help Center says: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." Though that's probably standard Stack Exchange boilerplate, and maybe someone should start a discussion on Mi Yodeya Meta about removing that bit of boilerplate from that help article of ours.

Answer (score 1):

Rav Peretz Moncharsh at [Revach](http://revach.net/ask/article.php?id=2084) writes regarding raw challah dough

> The proper beracha is Shehakol.

See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/61530/13811) where Brachot 6:3 is quoted as a source to say shehakol on raw dough.