# Do I make hamotzi over raw dough?

Tags: halacha, blessing, hamotzi-beracha

If I am making challah and want to taste the dough before baking would I make hamotzi or would it be adamah and shehakol for flour and eggs since it's not considered לחם מן הארץ yet?

Comment: Do you plan on swallowing it? Maybe you don't need a bracha at all? What about netilas yadiem?

Comment: Yes I would swallow it, like tasting it to see if it's salty enough...

Comment: For you to make Hamotzi the bread has to be baked. Shehakol is appropriate.

Comment: Potential dupe: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/43699/what-is-the-blessing-on-dough

Answer (score 2):

You need to make Shehakol because dough isn't intended for eating

Source: Brachot 6:3

Comment: A source would improve this answer

Comment: To add to this answer the general rule that any food eaten in a state in which it is not normally eaten 'downgrades' the required before and after bracha.